# When creating hive managed bucketing table it is converting to external table

Tags: pyspark, hive, hdfs, hiveql, bucket

I have created a hive bucket table using below command:

```
CREATE TABLE sales_bucketed_notrsc_3 (id INT, fname STRING) 
CLUSTERED BY (id) INTO 10 BUCKETS 
TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='false');
```

But, after performing above command, the table is created as external table. Don't know why??

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                   createtab_stmt                   |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `sales_bucketed_notrsc_3`(   |
|   `id` int,                                        |
|   `fname` string)                                  |
| CLUSTERED BY (                                     |
|   id)                                              |
| INTO 10 BUCKETS                                    |
| ROW FORMAT SERDE                                   |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'      |
| STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                              |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'  |
| OUTPUTFORMAT                                       |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' |
| LOCATION                                           |
|/warehouse/tablespace/external/hive/sales_bucketed_notrsc_3' |
| TBLPROPERTIES (                                    |
|   'TRANSLATED_TO_EXTERNAL'='TRUE',                 |
|   'bucketing_version'='2',                         |
|   'external.table.purge'='TRUE',                   |
|   'transient_lastDdlTime'='1631200197',            |
|   'translated_to_external'='false')                |
+----------------------------------------------------+
20 rows selected (0.188 seconds)
```

If, we create without ANY TBLPROPERTIES then it is creating a managed table. But the no# of bucketing files is not created as expected.

```
 CREATE TABLE sales_bucketed_1 (id INT, fname STRING) CLUSTERED BY (id) INTO 10 BUCKETS;
```

```
[root]# hdfs dfs -ls /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/sales_bucketed_1
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hive hive          0 2021-09-09 20:59 /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/sales_bucketed_1/delta_0000001_0000001_0000
drwxr-xr-x   - hive hive          0 2021-09-09 21:01 /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/sales_bucketed_1/delta_0000002_0000002_0000
[root]#
```

Comment: What if you add property 'EXTERNAL'='FALSE'? What is interesting there are two TRANSLATED_TO_EXTERNAL properties in your  createtab_stmt  - one uppercased and one lowercased: 'translated_to_external'='false'